# Error Exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Comp][Clnt]-303. Capability is not supported'

Tags: delphi, firedac

With FireDac, I have error when call CloneCursor.

```
procedure TFDDataSet.CloneCursor(ASource: TFDDataSet; AReset,
  AKeepSettings: Boolean);
begin
 ...
    ASource.FetchAll; //<- exception raise here
...
end;
```

Here is function where i call CloneCursor

```
procedure TTestDM.tblCt11AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  tblCt11Tmp: TFDMemTable;
begin
  ...
  tblCt11Tmp := TFDMemTable.Create(self);
  try
    tblCt11Tmp.CloneCursor(DataSet as TFDDataSet, False, True);
    ...
  finally
    tblCt11Tmp.Free;
  end;
```

If I edit each row of ct11 on GUI and move to other row of ct11, procedure tblCt11AfterPost work well.

But I scan ct11, edit it and post ct11, procedure tblCt11AfterPost will raise error in CloneCursor

```
 if tblCt11.Locate('stt_rec', tblPh11stt_rec.Value, []) then
      repeat
        if not (tblCt11.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
          tblCt11.Edit;

           //edit tblCt11 here

          tblCt11.Post;
      until not tblCt11.LocateEx('stt_rec', tblPh11stt_rec.Value, [lxoFromCurrent]);
```

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Aren't you creating too many cloned temporary dataset views in a quite possibly frequently triggered method? Cloning cursor is useful e.g. when one needs a different view on the data that are shared with another dataset.

Comment: @Victoria, I only clone one time tblCt11 (it is tblCt11Tmp). I want create different view of tblCt11

Comment: Why in the world would you want to clone the cursor after every single POST?

Comment: @KenWhite I want to calc some field of ct11 and update it to other table. I know there is other way like CopyDataSet, user TFDQuery (now i change to  use TFDQuery) but I want to know why CloneCursor has error when i use it in scan but ok when i edit it GUI. Sorry for my English.